# C# MySql Storing multiple database rows in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm struggling a bit with this. I want to get the list of ids from the database where a certain value is equal to a certain value in the row. This call will likely return multiple ids. I want to store the value in the ids returned in a list or arraylist in the c# code but I am finding this troublesome. I have the code up to here:

```
        string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT idprojects FROM `test`.`projects` WHERE application_layers = " + applicationTiers + "";
        connection.Open();

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
     MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);

     List<string> array = new List<string>();

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idprojects FROM `test`.`projects` WHERE application_layers = " + applicationTiers, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (Reader.Read())
                    {
                        array.Add(Reader["idprojects"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        string[] ret= array.ToArray();
```